# Integrating Galen framework with Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, galen

I want to integrate Galen and Cucumber. My intention is to run Galen specs configuration in Cucumber features steps.
To do so i write the following :

```
public class First extends GalenTestBase{
    @Given("^First Step$")
    public void firstStep() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("First step runs");
        TestDevice device = new TestDevice("mobile", new Dimension(450, 800), asList("mobile"));
        load("/");
        checkLayout("/specs/welcomePage.spec", device.getTags());

    }
}
```

Which `GalenTestBase` is the class with same name from https://github.com/galenframework/galen-sample-java-tests.git and `First`(name of the class) is name of feature.

The problem is i getting *`java.lang.RuntimeException: The driver is not instantiated yet`*.
I think it is because driver instantiation which is in `@BeforeMethod` of `GalenTestNgTestBase`.

Any suggestion how can i achieve such integration?

Comment: so you just cloned the linked repo locally and added your above class, right?

Comment: which version of Galen you're using?

Comment: @hypery2k No exactly. We changed some more. But this one was most important :). We use latest version of Galen that accessible from their website.

Comment: Is there anyway to pass Driver object to java test cases? like what you can do in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using my sample project (https://github.com/hypery2k/galen_samples) and see how to pass a driver instance in GalenBaseTest.java